# How to make NPC in roblox walk around normally then when it sees a player it runs after them

Tags: lua, roblox

The titles explains it all, I'm trying to make a roblox npc walk around the maze normally, then when it sees the player, it starts running after the player to kill it, I have the NPC, I have the killing part, I just need the code for the NPC walking around normally and the code for the NPC detecting the player then running after them. Thanks! :D

edited: heres my code

```
debugMode = false
targetNPCs = false

--

h = script.Parent.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
pathService = game:GetService("PathfindingService")
targetV = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Target")

function closestTargetAndPath()
 local humanoids = {}
 if targetNPCs then
 local function recurse(o)
 for _,obj in pairs(o:GetChildren()) do
 if obj:IsA("Model") then
 if obj:findFirstChild("Humanoid") and obj:findFirstChild("Torso") and obj.Humanoid ~= h and obj.Humanoid.Health > 0 and not obj:findFirstChild("ForceField") then
 table.insert(humanoids,obj.Humanoid)
 end
 end
 recurse(obj)
 end
 end
 recurse(workspace)
 else
 for _,v in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
 if v.Character and v.Character:findFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart") and v.Character:findFirstChild("Humanoid") and v.Character.Humanoid.Health > 0 and not v:findFirstChild("ForceField") then
 table.insert(humanoids,v.Character.Humanoid)
 end
 end
 end
 local closest,path,dist
 for _,humanoid in pairs(humanoids) do
 local myPath = pathService:ComputeRawPathAsync(h.Torso.Position,humanoid.Torso.Position,500)
 if myPath.Status ~= Enum.PathStatus.FailFinishNotEmpty then
 -- Now that we have a successful path, we need to figure out how far we need to actually travel to reach this point.
 local myDist = 0
 local previous = h.Torso.Position
 for _,point in pairs(myPath:GetPointCoordinates()) do
 myDist = myDist + (point-previous).magnitude
 previous = point
 end
 if not dist or myDist < dist then -- if true, this is the closest path so far.
 closest = humanoid
 path = myPath
 dist = myDist
 end
 end
 end
 return closest,path
end

function goToPos(loc)
 h:MoveTo(loc)
 local distance = (loc-h.Torso.Position).magnitude
 local start = tick()
 while distance > 4 do
 if tick()-start > distance/h.WalkSpeed then -- Something may have gone wrong. Just break.
 break
 end
 distance = (loc-h.Torso.Position).magnitude
 wait()
 end
end

while wait() do
 local target,path = closestTargetAndPath()
 local didBreak = false
 local targetStart
 if target and h.Torso then
 targetV.Value = target
 targetStart = target.Torso.Position
 roaming = false
 local previous = h.Torso.Position
 local points = path:GetPointCoordinates()
 local s = #points > 1 and 2 or 1
 for i = s,#points do
 local point = points[i]
 if didBreak then 
 break
 end
 if target and target.Torso and target.Health > 0 then
 if (target.Torso.Position-targetStart).magnitude < 1.5 then
 local pos = previous:lerp(point,.5)
 local moveDir = ((pos - h.Torso.Position).unit * 2)
 goToPos(previous:lerp(point,.5))
 previous = point
 end
 else
 didBreak = true
 break
 end
 end
 else
 targetV.Value = nil
 end
 if not didBreak and targetStart then
 goToPos(targetStart)
 end
end
```

Comment: Heyo, StackOverflow is meant to help you debug problems in your code. What have you tried to get your NPC walking around? What isn't working? Please update your question with the code that you've tried and we can help you debug the problems with it.

Comment: please read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

I won't provide any code as you have not shown any efforts to solve that problem.

Enter "roblox npc" into [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). Click the second hit:

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Moving-NPCs-Between-Points

This covers the walking around part and also links this

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Pathfinding

which covers more complex movements.

The seeing part is done with ray casting

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Raycasting

If you can cast a ray from the NPC to your player calculate a path to that player and attack.

Comment: It's also possible to use magnitude.